# IIS returns 500 instead of 401

Tags: iis, web-config, authorization, backend

I'm using OAuth authorization on my back-end server. The thing is locally, when a user tries to send an unauthorized request, the server returns 401. The problem is when I push the sever, an unauthorized request send 500 instead of 401. The server doesn't throw any exception, since I check the logs and everything, and there are no exception.

Comment: It could be an unlogged exception or a very low-level item. Is the backend server configured correctly?

Comment: @EnderCode, were you be able to figure it out? I'm getting the same error. It was working initially but after some change (in IIS, pools?) it began to return 500 instead of 401.